# How do I use Hyper-V with dual monitor support?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hyper-v

I recently installed Windows 8.1 Pro Build 9600 on my computer, and then I enabled the Hyper-V Windows Feature. I created a virtual machine running Windows 7 Enterprise.

What I can't figure out is how do I connect to it so that I can have dual monitor support. In fact, the window that opens up isn't even expandable to fit my primary monitor, and if I change it to "Full Screen" it takes up the entire primary monitor, but the actual viewing area is still much smaller than what is possibly available and just centered.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers that allow you to adjust the screen resolultion within the virtual machine? Sounds like you have not. Expanding the VM to two monitors is an entirely different problem on that isn't easy to resolve

Comment: @Ramhound: I wasn't really sure where to start. I am still fairly new to Hyper-V (I've used Virtual Box in the past). So, actually no. I Have not installed any additional drivers.

Comment: Well just like VirtualBox it has extensions to enable basic video driver support.  you need to do that before we can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that RemoteDesktop can support dual screen (but not every of them).
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7s-remote-desktop-connection/

To summarize :

```
1) Start "Remote Desktop Connection"
2) Click "Show Options"
3) Goto "Display" tab
4) Set "Full Screen" resolution
5) Mark "Use all my montors for the remote session"
6) Click "Connect"
```

Comment: Please summarize your answer instead of only providing a link.  Consider the possibility that the link will not work sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

RDP to the VM and add the [`/multimon`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx) switch:

```
mstsc /multimon /v (VM NAME OR IP)
```

Comment: Make sure you use the computer name of Virtual Machine not the name mentioned in HYPER-V manager.

Comment: AFAIK This requires the guest having multiple virtual monitors, which Hyper-V doesn't support.